# Gujarati language issue in php and mysql. Gujarati fonts are converted to question mark while rendering in browser

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have data stored in mysql. it is in gujarati language. But while rendering it in browser it is converted to ???. It is working properly in my localhost. I use utf-8 encoding, charaset in database and on the live server is also same. collation is also same. but still the gujarati sting is converted to ?????? like so. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: you can check with the character set and collation for the column of the table character set  should be utf-8 and the collation should be utf8_unicode_ci plz try it, hope it will help

Comment: I have the same and also recheck it. it is same as you suggested. but not working

Comment: See "question mark" (not "black diamond") in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored